# Presto DB + what we can do in case of some presto workers are down + auto start

Tags: linux, presto, trino

Dear friends and college

we installed presto cluster as the follwing

```
1 presto coordinator 
320 presto workers
```

we are satisfied with the Presto performance , and the presto User interface is impressive

how ever we notice that

presto coordinator not have high availability

but what is the most that we are worry about is that , we not see any auto start configuration on the presto workers

its means that in case of one of the presto worker is down then ( from my understanding ) presto not have the ability to identify this issued and start the presto worker after some time

**am I right here ?**

or maybe Presto worker have some configuration that can start the presto worker in case its down after some X min  ?

Answer (score 2):

This is something we (Presto community) are currently working on, please follow: [High Availability](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/391). We are also invite you to put your comments there, so we could verify if your use case will be covered.

Also, if you are using AWS for Presto you might to consider checking StarburstData offering for [Presto Coordinator High Availability](https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/aws/high-availability.html)

Comment: I understand that you not have solution for the first note , but what about auto start for the worker presto node ?

Comment: anyway the link is broken , please assist

Comment: @Judy, Link is fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @KingDavid, there is no such date yet.

Answer (score 1):

I am using cron job for this task 
I will explain

first in my presto cluster , I created service for each presto worker

so by the following we can see the presto status:

example:

```
systemctl status presto.service
● presto.service - Perforce Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/presto.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-08-14 15:35:15 UTC; 2h 51min ago
 Main PID: 22853 (presto-server)
    Tasks: 273
```

about the cron Job:

under `/etc/cron.d`

create cron Job file , and simple script that will execute from the corn-job each 5 min

script will verify the presto service , and if service is down then script will start the presto as:

```
systemctl start presto.service
```